# Errors when moving between a tableView and a view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7, uinavigationcontroller

I have a Navigation Controller which has a tableView controller connected to it. The tableView has a segue to a view. This segue is called from program, after an edge swipe is done. The `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer` is applied to the view.
Here is the code where I call the segue.

```
-(void)handleEdgeSwipe:(UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer *)swipe
{

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SettingS" sender:self.navigationController];

}
```

The segue is performed, but when I press the back button, the tableView controller is not shown, only the background image with a back button. This is what I get in the console:

```
2014-07-09 16:54:34.322 APPNAME[3313:60b] nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar

2014-07-09 16:54:34.676 APPNAME[3313:60b] Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted.

2014-07-09 16:54:34.827 APPNAME[3313:60b] Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for FDDSettingsViewController: 0x10945d370.
```

and this is the error I get:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't add self as subview'
```

Anyone any ideas?

EDIT!

Problem solved.
It was the gesture recognizer firing twice, I added an if statement to check whether it just began. Code now:

```
-(void)handleEdgeSwipe:(UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer *)swipe
{
if (swipe.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SettingS" sender:nil];
}

}
```

Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

The segue shouldn't really come from the UITableView. The segue should come from the navigationcontroller. Can you confirm that you are attaching the segue from the UINavigationController rather than the UITableView?

Comment: What do you mean? The code is in the file for the tableViewController but the sender is the navigationController.

Comment: When you connected the segue, did you connect it from the UITableView or the ViewController?

Comment: How are you handling the back button? The error you are getting is due to the fact that you are calling a segue before the proper completion of another segue. This can happen is your UITableView is calling the segue in storyboard as well as in -(void)handleEdgeSwipe:(UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer *)swipe. Does it segue if you comment out [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SettingS" sender:self.navigationController]; and just click on the UITableView cell?

Comment: It does not segue if it's commented out. The tableView cell is no way connected with this. The back button is handled by the navigation controller.

Comment: And how are you handling the back button segue back?